# MS Access VBA - Possibility to export userform as PDF

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba, export

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am currently testing code in Access VBA that will export a form and all of its controls as it appears directly to the user (while on one record). In short, I have a calculation tool with many inputs which calculates an international trips estimated total cost and saves all the inputs to a table, in order to record costs per unique trip.

Currently (on-click button), I am exporting one record from the table into an excel workbook and have a lengthy P.I.T.A. excel MACRO that re-formats the raw data into the format that is similar to the user-form in Access. Is there any way (other than to screenshot the form) to get a "print preview" and save as a PDF or any other output.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this and I appreciate any insight regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can export your form to pdf using this command

docmd.OutputTo acOutputForm,"your form name", acformatpdf, "export file path"

Comment: When I run this I get a runtime error 2501 the OutputTo action was canceled..looked this up and tried saving to a drive in my network, same thing happened. After further research I don't think it's possible to export my form with with saved values from a control source (being a table that I store each unique trip) having them be present on my exported form.